# Neo4j errorMessages': {'Invalid input \'a\': expected \'u/U\'}

Tags: neo4j, cypher, unique-constraint, neo4j-apoc

I have the following cypher code

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
        "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM $url AS row 
         WITH row {{.*}}
         RETURN row",
        "CALL apoc.merge.node(['House'], 
                              {{id : row.ID}}, 
                              apoc.map.submap(row,['household']),
                              apoc.map.submap(row,['household']))
        YIELD node AS n1
        CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n1, ['House'])
        YIELD node as n2
        CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name IF NOT EXISTS ON (n:House) ASSERT n.household IS UNIQUE
        YIELD node as n3
        RETURN COUNT(n1)
        ",
        {{batchSize: {batch_size}, iterateList: true, parallel:false, params: {{url: '{url}'}} }})
```

I get the errorMessages': {'Invalid input 'a': expected 'u/U' CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name IF NOT EXISTS ON (n:House) ASSERT n.household IS UNIQUE}
**do you know how to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `CREATE CONSTRAINT` is invalid- it should not be part of a Cypher query such as LOAD CSV.

Create the constraint first:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name IF NOT EXISTS ON (n:House) ASSERT n.household IS UNIQUE
```

And then you can run a new Cypher statement to load data.

Unrelated note: You do not need to use apoc.periodic.iterate to batch the LOAD CSV, you can use a periodic commit too https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-setting-the-rate-of-periodic-commits